# Accessing same SP site using multiple URL's

Tags: site, alternate-access-mapping, public-website

Quite interesting feature in Sharepoint using AAM. Isn't it?

I just need one liner to **logically** and **physically** understand the same.

Answer (score 1):

AAm is a web app level setting, it give you flexiblity to map Public Url to Internal Urls. We can configure 5 public urls in different zone( default,intranet,internet,extranet,custom).

> Alternate access mappings enable a Web application that receives a
>   request for an internal URL, in one of the five authentication zones,
>   to return pages that contain links to the public URL for the zone. You
>   can associate a Web application with a collection of mappings between
>   internal and public URLs. Internal refers to the URL of a Web request
>   as it is received by Windows SharePoint Services 3.0. Public refers to
>   the URL of an externally accessible Web site.
>
> Multiple internal URLs can be associated with a single public URL.
>   Mapping collections can contain up to five authentication zones, but
>   each zone can only have a single public URL. Mapping collections
>   correspond to the following authentication zones:

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288609(v=office.12).aspx)

> AAM tells SharePoint how to map web requests (for example, browsing to
>   the homepage of a SharePoint site) to the correct web application and
>   site so that SharePoint can serve the correct content back to you. It
>   then tells SharePoint what URL the users should be taken to as they
>   interact with SharePoint.

[Source](https://blogs.office.com/2010/08/16/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1-of-3/)